# Uncaught Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten

Tags: angular, google-chrome

Using latest Angular (development environment or production) with latest Google Chrome (Mac) I get this error if I return to the website with the browser navigation functionality, or if the website is loaded from cache.

I have tried disabling all addons and things in my Chrome browser that could cause this.

I can reproduce the issue by just going to a random live Angular website online, for example:

https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com

Reproduce by first going to any website, then open the above url, click "back" and then "forward". Repeat a couple of times. The error will occur most of the time when "returning" to the website.

It is currently affecting all my live Angular websites so I am really concerned that this is a real issue not just affecting me.

Comment: did you have any luck figuring it out?

Comment: No, have you experienced the same issue @ditoslav? I am not the only one?

Comment: I have the same issue and I've seen some more questions regarding this on stackoverflow for 2019. I only have this issue when creating a --prod build so right now I published on firebase my dev build but I'll have to fix this at some point. I tried switching to angular 9.next but it didn't help

Comment: I am having the same issue suddenly with Angular8 but was ok to run in Firefox. Any solution work for your guys?

Comment: Reseting Chrome settings solved the issue for me.